# Is it possible to build an iOS mobile application for the App Store to export iMessages to PDF?

Tags: ios, pdf, export, imessage

I found many products that can do this but they are desktop-based, e.g., Mac and Windows. The apps I found in the App Store still required a desktop to complete the process.

Goal: Build an iOS app to export iMessage to PDF (no use of a desktop)

Challenge: Does Apple allow this type of functionality and or will they approve the app?

If you have any reference links and or documentation it would be much appreciated.

Comment: No, for privacy reasons apps can not access iMessage content.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible as there is no API that allows apps to access iMessage content. This is a privacy restriction.